# COPY FROM .csv file to a remote PostgreSQL Database (Running in Linux Server)

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, csv

I'm trying to import data from .csv file to a PostgreSQL database hosted in a Linux Server, using the following command:

```
COPY areas_brasil FROM 'C:/Temp/RELATORIO_DTB_BRASIL_MUNICIPIO.csv' with delimiter '|' null 'NULL';
```

But i'm receiving the following error:

> ERROR:  could not open file
>   "C:/Temp/RELATORIO_DTB_BRASIL_MUNICIPIO.csv" for reading: No such file
>   or directory TIP:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process
>   to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's
>   \copy.

The .csv file is in a client computer (running on Windows 10) in which i have administrator access to the database hosted in the server (running on Linux - Debian).

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message suggests: using \copy command instead?
COPY refers to postgres server directory while \COPY file paths are relative the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

`COPY .. FROM 'path'` assumes that the file is located in the server. If you wish execute COPY without having the file into the database server, you can either use `\copy` or just use the `STDIN` of [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/index.html) from your client console, e.g. in unix systems (you have to find the `cat` and `|` equivalent for Windows):

```
$ cat file.csv | psql yourdb -c "COPY areas_brasil FROM STDIN DELIMITER '|';"
```

Using `\COPY` inside of `psql` it can be done like this:

```
\COPY areas_brasil FROM '/home/jones/file.csv' DELIMITER '|';
```

See this [`answer`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18821/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-a-postgresql-database-using-copy) for more details.